# open a menu from OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to open a menu from a `OnClickListener`
without using the method `onCreateOptionsMenu`
**My code:**

```
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.week);  //your icon
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v ) {

        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to show/hide a menu item based on actions from users. To do that you must use `onCreateOptionsMenu` and whenever you want to show/hide the menu item, then call `invalidateOptionsMenu` (this method will call `onCreateOptionsMenu` again).

```
boolean mShowMenu = false;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item);
    item.setVisible(showMenu);
    return true;
}
```

And in your code, when you want to show menu item.

```
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.week);  //your icon
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v ) {
            mShowMenu = true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
```

And give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much but i don't get what should i put in the:
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_menu_item);

and do you ment to mShowMenu insted of showMenu

Comment: To show the menu you must define it in an xml file (in menu res folder). mShowMenu and showMenu are the same, it's just coding convention I used. So what do you want to display on the menu, an icon, a text?

Comment: Thanks i just want the reguler menu bottun to be gone and the menu will see trow the OnClickListener its an icon on the toolBar insted of item

Comment: Do you define any xml file in res/menu forder in your app?

Answer (score 1):

You should need to create menu Interface in xml File Like this

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:title="Setting"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/my_activity"
    android:title="My Activity"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/btn_radio"/>
```

After that in the Java code of a particular class You need to create the code like this;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

  if (id == R.id.my_activity) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent1);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.settings) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Setting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hopefully this may resolve your problem

Comment: cant i open the menu from the code i entered before?